# Is there an API for accessing Mail's recent recipients list in iOS?

Tags: ios, email

I worked on a custom email composer with address autocompletion that used the Address Book database (ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople). The standard email composer also has a recent recipients list, which are addresses recently sent to but not saved as a contact. Is this list available in a public API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third party app getting access to this list, breaks user privacy and hence not allowed.